# How to sort NSMutableArray in Alphabetical order according to there values in iPhone

Tags: iphone, sorting, nsmutablearray

in my app i am getting some queue details value from web server, i have stored the queue id and queue title in NSMutableArray, now i need to sort queue title in alphabetical order, however if i am doing this all my queue id values got mixed up, so how do make this that queue title should be sorted in alphabetical order and stored there  respective   queue id values.

```
NSArray *DicPicklistValues = [tempPickList valueForKey:@"PickListValue"];
for(int i=0;i<[DicPicklistValues count];i++){

    NSDictionary *tempDic = [DicPicklistValues objectAtIndex:i];
    [queueId addObject:[tempDic objectForKey:@"Value"]];
    [queueLabel addObject:[tempDic objectForKey:@"Label"]];
}

[queueLabel sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could sort the `DicPicklistValues` array *before* building the `queueId` and `queueLabel` arrays. (Btw. names of variables normally start with a lower case letter.)

```
NSArray *dicPicklistValues = [tempPickList valueForKey:@"PickListValue"];
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"Label"
                        ascending:YES
                        selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
NSArray *sortedPicklistValues = [dicPicklistValues sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];
// now use sortedPicklistValues instead of dicPicklistValues ...
```

There is also an easier way to build the `queueId` and `queueLabel` arrays:

```
NSArray *queueId = [sortedPicklistValues valueForKey:@"Value"];
NSArray *queueLabel = [sortedPicklistValues valueForKey:@"Label"];
```